# Unable to create 2 machine environment variables and execute another command via a Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to create 2 "machine" environment variables and also execute a command via a single Scheduled Task.  The scheduled task should immediately run and delete itself.  The scheduled task should be executing as the current logged-in desktop user.

Below are the 3 items I need to execute:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AppA', (Get-StartApps -Name 'PowerShell (Tools1)').AppID, 'Machine')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AppB', (Get-StartApps -Name 'PowerShell (Tools2)').AppID, 'Machine')
Export-StartLayout -path 'C:\temp\Orig.xml'
```

**Note:**  I do NOT want to depend on an external script; which is why I have such a long line of code for `$action`

When I run the code below, almost always, none of the commands are executed.  Very rarely, a single environment variable get's created.  If it's impossible to do this reliably in a single task, I'm hoping someone could show me how to do this reliably in 3 separate tasks. It seems even if I do 3 separate tasks, the results are still inconsistent/unreliable.

**Code:**

```PoSH
$AppA = (Get-StartApps -Name 'Windows PowerShell ISE (x86)').AppID
$AppB = (Get-StartApps -Name 'Outlook').AppID
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Argument "-noprofile -windowstyle hidden -command ( [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AppA', $AppA, 'Machine') ; [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AppB', $AppB, 'Machine') ; Export-StartLayout -path 'C:\temp\Orig.xml' )"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (get-date).AddSeconds(4); $trigger.EndBoundary = (get-date).AddSeconds(8).ToString('s')
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem).UserName -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -StartWhenAvailable -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter 00:00:12
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "2 envvars and Export-StartLayout" -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal -Settings $settings
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did run each command separately.  They also produce inconsistent results.. even if username variable is reliable every time in my case.  I'm not running this on a VM.

Comment: Im just guessing.. but it appears to be timing-related,  I noticed changing the number of seconds in `$trigger` and `$settings` seems to make a different; but, I'm not sure what the optimal timing is for it to work reliably every time.